# Changing Chef Server IP Address

Tags: chef

My understanding was that the Chef server is identified to clients by the FQDN, rather than by the IP address (and all the configuration I've done suggested this as well).

I found myself in the position of having to relocate the Chef server (as a full system image, with updated network scripts) to another VLAN and will lose the IP as a result.

Assuming the FQDN resolves to the new IP, should my workstation (knife, etc.) function normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything should work the same, unless you've done any modifications to the api_fqdn, bookshelf or lb vip addresses.

The only real state that absolutely needs to be there is the client certificates as these are the authentication and authorization for the existing knife users and nodes.

Comment: Thanks! That shouldn't be an issue (none of that would be modified)